# The dynamic programming solution 9.1 on CTCI

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am recently studying the CTCI and have some questions about the solution given on Question 9.1. I think the solution might be wrong.

The question is

> A child is running up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can run up the stairs.

And th solution given is, which can be found [here](https://github.com/fluency03/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%209/Question9_1/Question.java):

```
public class Question {

    public static int countWaysDP(int n, int[] map) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (map[n] > -1) {
            return map[n];
        } else {
            map[n] = countWaysDP(n - 1, map) + 
                     countWaysDP(n - 2, map) + 
                     countWaysDP(n - 3, map);
            return map[n];
        }
    }

    public static int countWaysRecursive(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return countWaysRecursive(n - 1) + countWaysRecursive(n - 2) + countWaysRecursive(n - 3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int[] map = new int[30 + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                map[j] = -1;
            }
            int c1 = countWaysDP(i, map);
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long d1 = t2 - t1;

            long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int c2 = countWaysRecursive(i);
            long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long d2 = t4 - t3;          
            System.out.println(i + " " + c1 + " " + c2 + " " + d1 + " " + d2);
        }
    }

}
```

In the above solution, when `countWaysDP(int n, int[] map)` is given integer 1, instead of returning 1, it will return -1. Because the program will go to branch `(map[n] > -1)`, and it will return `map[n]`, which is `map[1]`, which is `-1` as it is initialized.

Comment: No, the `if (map[n] > -1)` test will fail and the final `else` branch will execute correctly, because -1 is not > -1.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My mistake.